# 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes' still not solved

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I need to have *total_loss* as an output of my model, I did this:

```
ama3_forward_loss1  = self.parameters["beta_z"] * kl_z0 + x0y0 + kl_a_z0 + self.parameters["beta_d"] * kl_z1z2 + x1y1
ama3_forward_loss2  = self.parameters["beta_z"] * kl_z0 + x0y0 + kl_a_z0 + x1y2
ama3_backward_loss1 = self.parameters["beta_z"] * kl_z1 + x1y1 + kl_a_z1 + self.parameters["beta_d"] * kl_z0z3 + x0y0
ama3_backward_loss2 = self.parameters["beta_z"] * kl_z1 + x1y1 + kl_a_z1 + x0y3

total_loss = Lambda(self.add_)([ama3_forward_loss1, ama3_forward_loss2, ama3_backward_loss1, ama3_backward_loss2])
    

net = Model(x, [y_aae, total_loss])
```

returns:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

full error log below:

```
  File latplan/network.py line 126 function build : self._build_around(*args,**kwargs)
                    self = <latplan.model.ConvolutionalConcreteDetNormalizedLogitAddBidirectionalTransitionAEPlus object at 0x7f0c187a2fd0>
                    args = (((2, 0), (28, 1), (28, 2), ('...<1 more>', None)),)
                  kwargs = {}

  File latplan/mixins/encoder_decoder.py line 94 function _build_around : super()._build_around(input_shape)
                    self = <latplan.model.ConvolutionalConcreteDetNormalizedLogitAddBidirectionalTransitionAEPlus object at 0x7f0c187a2fd0>
             input_shape = ((2, 0), (28, 1), (28, 2), ('...<1 more>', None))

  File latplan/model.py line 631 function _build_around : super()._build_around(input_shape)
             input_shape = ((2, 0), (28, 1), (28, 2), ('...<1 more>', None))
                    self = <latplan.model.ConvolutionalConcreteDetNormalizedLogitAddBidirectionalTransitionAEPlus object at 0x7f0c187a2fd0>

  File latplan/model.py line 1525 function _build_around : super()._build_around(input_shape)
             input_shape = ((2, 0), (28, 1), (28, 2), ('...<1 more>', None))
                       A = 6000
         initial_weights = []
                    self = <latplan.model.ConvolutionalConcreteDetNormalizedLogitAddBidirectionalTransitionAEPlus object at 0x7f0c187a2fd0>

  File latplan/model.py line 499 function _build_around : super()._build_around(input_shape[1:])
                    self = <latplan.model.ConvolutionalConcreteDetNormalizedLogitAddBidirectionalTransitionAEPlus object at 0x7f0c187a2fd0>
             input_shape = ((2, 0), (28, 1), (28, 2), ('...<1 more>', None))

  File latplan/model.py line 224 function _build_around : super()._build_around(input_shape)
                    self = <latplan.model.ConvolutionalConcreteDetNormalizedLogitAddBidirectionalTransitionAEPlus object at 0x7f0c187a2fd0>
             input_shape = (28, 28, 3)

  File latplan/mixins/encoder_decoder.py line 40 function _build_around : super()._build_around(state_input_shape)
                    self = <latplan.model.ConvolutionalConcreteDetNormalizedLogitAddBidirectionalTransitionAEPlus object at 0x7f0c187a2fd0>
       state_input_shape = (28, 28, 3)

  File latplan/network.py line 138 function _build_around : return self._build_primary(*args,**kwargs)
                    self = <latplan.model.ConvolutionalConcreteDetNormalizedLogitAddBidirectionalTransitionAEPlus object at 0x7f0c187a2fd0>
                    args = ((28, 28, 3),)
                  kwargs = {}

  File latplan/model.py line 1037 function _build_primary : super()._build_primary(input_shape)
                    self = <latplan.model.ConvolutionalConcreteDetNormalizedLogitAddBidirectionalTransitionAEPlus object at 0x7f0c187a2fd0>
             input_shape = (28, 28, 3)

  File latplan/model.py line 865 function _build_primary : super()._build_primary(input_shape)
                    self = <latplan.model.ConvolutionalConcreteDetNormalizedLogitAddBidirectionalTransitionAEPlus object at 0x7f0c187a2fd0>
             input_shape = (28, 28, 3)

  File latplan/model.py line 1674 function _build_primary : self.net = Model(x, [y_aae, total_loss])
                    self = <latplan.model.ConvolutionalConcreteDetNormalizedLogitAddBidirectionalTransitionAEPlus object at 0x7f0c187a2fd0>
             input_shape = (28, 28, 3)
                       x = <tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 2, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>
                       _ = {}
                   x_pre = <tf.Tensor 'strided_slice:0' shape=(?, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>
                   x_suc = <tf.Tensor 'strided_slice_1:0' shape=(?, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>
                       z = <tf.Tensor 'dmerge_2/concat:0' shape=(?, 2, 300) dtype=float32>
                   z_pre = <tf.Tensor 'binary_concrete_1/concrete_0/cond/Merge:0' shape=(?, 300) dtype=float32>
                   z_suc = <tf.Tensor 'binary_concrete_1_1/concrete_1/cond/Merge:0' shape=(?, 300) dtype=float32>
                       y = <tf.Tensor 'dmerge_3/concat:0' shape=(?, 2, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>
                   y_pre = <tf.Tensor 'activation_1/Identity:0' shape=(?, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>
                   y_suc = <tf.Tensor 'activation_1_1/Identity:0' shape=(?, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>
                   l_pre = <tf.Tensor 'dense_5/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 300) dtype=float32>
                   l_suc = <tf.Tensor 'dense_5_1/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 300) dtype=float32>
                   p_pre = <tf.Tensor 'Sigmoid:0' shape=(?, 300) dtype=float32>
                   p_suc = <tf.Tensor 'Sigmoid_1:0' shape=(?, 300) dtype=float32>
                  action = <tf.Tensor 'gumbel_softmax_1/gumbel_0/cond/Merge:0' shape=(?, 1, 6000) dtype=float32>
               z_suc_aae = <tf.Tensor 'binary_concrete_2/concrete_2/cond/Merge:0' shape=(?, 300) dtype=float32>
               z_pre_aae = <tf.Tensor 'binary_concrete_3/concrete_3/cond/Merge:0' shape=(?, 300) dtype=float32>
               y_suc_aae = <tf.Tensor 'activation_1_2/Identity:0' shape=(?, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>
               y_pre_aae = <tf.Tensor 'activation_1_3/Identity:0' shape=(?, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>
                   z_aae = <tf.Tensor 'dmerge_4/concat:0' shape=(?, 2, 300) dtype=float32>
                   y_aae = <tf.Tensor 'dmerge_5/concat:0' shape=(?, 2, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>
                l_action = <tf.Tensor 'dense_2/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 6000) dtype=float32>
               l_suc_aae = <tf.Tensor 'add_1/add:0' shape=(?, 300) dtype=float32>
               l_pre_aae = <tf.Tensor 'add_2/add:0' shape=(?, 300) dtype=float32>
                       p = <tf.Tensor 'dmerge_6/concat:0' shape=(?, 2, 300) dtype=float32>
               p_pre_aae = <tf.Tensor 'Sigmoid_2:0' shape=(?, 300) dtype=float32>
               p_suc_aae = <tf.Tensor 'Sigmoid_3:0' shape=(?, 300) dtype=float32>
                   p_aae = <tf.Tensor 'dmerge_7/concat:0' shape=(?, 2, 300) dtype=float32>
              pdiff_z1z2 = <tf.Tensor 'Mean:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
              pdiff_z0z3 = <tf.Tensor 'Mean_1:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
              pdiff_z0z1 = <tf.Tensor 'Mean_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
              pdiff_z0z2 = <tf.Tensor 'Mean_3:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
              loss_trans = 0.0
             loss_states = 0.0
         additional_loss = <tf.Tensor 'Const_10:0' shape=() dtype=float32>
                   kl_z0 = <tf.Tensor 'Sum:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
                   kl_z1 = <tf.Tensor 'Sum_1:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
                 kl_a_z0 = <tf.Tensor 'Sum_5:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
                 kl_a_z1 = <tf.Tensor 'Sum_9:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
                 kl_z1z2 = <tf.Tensor 'Sum_10:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
                 kl_z0z3 = <tf.Tensor 'Sum_11:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
                    _rec = <bound method GaussianOutput.loss of <latplan.mixins.output.GaussianOutput object at 0x7f0d6eca9a60>>
                    x0y0 = <tf.Tensor 'Sum_12:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
                    x1y1 = <tf.Tensor 'Sum_13:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
                    x0y3 = <tf.Tensor 'Sum_14:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
                    x1y2 = <tf.Tensor 'Sum_15:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
      ama3_forward_loss1 = <tf.Tensor 'add_9:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
      ama3_forward_loss2 = <tf.Tensor 'add_12:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
     ama3_backward_loss1 = <tf.Tensor 'add_16:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
     ama3_backward_loss2 = <tf.Tensor 'add_19:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
      ama3_forward_elbo1 = <tf.Tensor 'add_23:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
      ama3_forward_elbo2 = <tf.Tensor 'add_26:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
     ama3_backward_elbo1 = <tf.Tensor 'add_30:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
     ama3_backward_elbo2 = <tf.Tensor 'add_33:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
                    elbo = <tf.Tensor 'truediv_8:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
              total_loss = <tf.Tensor 'lambda_28/add_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>

  File ../../../usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py line 91 function wrapper : return func(*args, **kwargs)
                       args = (<keras.engine.training.Model object at 0x7f0d665a39a0>, <tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 2, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>, [<tf.Tensor 'dmerge_5/concat:0' shape=(?, 2, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'lambda_28/add_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>])
                     kwargs = {}
                object_name = 'Model'
                  converted = []
                   old_name = 'output'
                   new_name = 'outputs'
    allowed_positional_args = []
      check_positional_args = False
                conversions = [('input', 'inputs'), ('output', 'outputs')]
                object_type = 'class'
               preprocessor = None
          value_conversions = []

  File ../../../usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py line 94 function __init__ : self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
                    self = <keras.engine.training.Model object at 0x7f0d665a39a0>
                    args = (<tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 2, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>, [<tf.Tensor 'dmerge_5/concat:0' shape=(?, 2, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'lambda_28/add_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>])
                  kwargs = {}

  File ../../../usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py line 236 function _init_graph_network : nodes, nodes_by_depth, layers, layers_by_depth = _map_graph_network(
                    self = <keras.engine.training.Model object at 0x7f0d665a39a0>
                  inputs = <tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 2, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>
                 outputs = [<tf.Tensor 'dmerge_5/concat:0' shape=(?, 2, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'lambda_28/add_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>]
                    name = None
                  kwargs = {}
                       x = <tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 2, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>
                   layer = <keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x7f0d6ec6d4c0>
              node_index = 0
            tensor_index = 0

  File ../../../usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py line 1418 function _map_graph_network : build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress,
                       inputs = [<tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 2, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>]
                      outputs = [<tf.Tensor 'dmerge_5/concat:0' shape=(?, 2, 28, 28, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'lambda_28/add_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>]
                 nodes_depths = {}
                layers_depths = {}
               finished_nodes = {<keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6ebb1820>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d667f5820>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d666a4040>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6ebdb850>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d66770850>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6c48b0a0>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6c44d0a0>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d66a298b0>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d669af8e0>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d66870100>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6c486910>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d669af910>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d668d0940>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d666cc940>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d66a39160>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6698f160>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d668d0970>
            nodes_in_progress = {<keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d66595a30>}
                            x = <tf.Tensor 'lambda_28/add_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
                        layer = <keras.layers.core.Lambda object at 0x7f0d6658dc70>
                   node_index = 0
                 tensor_index = 0
                layer_indices = {<keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f0d666a4c10>: 0, <keras.layers.core.Lambda object at 0x7f0d666a1190>: 1, <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f0d6ec65670>: 2, <keras.layers.core.Reshape object at 0x7f0d6ec65970>: 3, <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2DTranspose object at 0x7f0d6ec65700>: 4, <keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x7f0d6ec65d00>: 5, <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f0d6ec657c0>: 6, <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2DTranspose object at 0x7f0d6ec65610>: 7, <keras.layers.core.Reshape object at 0x7f0d6ec655e0>: 8, <keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x7f0d6ec65340>: 9, <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f0d6ec65310>: 10, <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f0d6ec651f0>: 11, <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f0d6c43ed90>: 12, <latplan.util.layers.BinaryConcrete object at 0x7f0d669193a0>: 13, <keras.layers.merge.Add object at 0x7f0d66a29040>: 14, <k
                network_nodes = {'conv2d_transpose_1_ib-2', 'conv2d_2_ib-1', 'dmerge_5_ib-0', 'conv2d_transpose_2_ib-3', 'conv2d_transpose_2_ib-2', 'reshape_4_ib-2', 'batch_normalization_10_ib-0', 'dense_8_ib-0', 'conv2d_1_ib-1', 'dropout_5_ib-3', 'dense_5_ib-1', 'lambda_14_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_7_ib-3', 'reshape_4_ib-3', 'binary_concrete_2_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_3_ib-1', 'reshape_3_ib-1', 'dense_5_ib-0', 'dropout_4_ib-2', 'activation_1_ib-2', 'batch_normalization_1_ib-0', 'lambda_18_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_7_ib-2', 'batch_normalization_6_ib-2', 'my_flatten_2_ib-0', 'binary_concrete_1_ib-0', 'dropout_3_ib-1', 'my_flatten_1_ib-0', 'gaussian_noise_1_ib-1', 'lambda_19_ib-0', 'dropout_5_ib-2', 'reshape_5_ib-3', 'dense_6_ib-3', 'reshape_3_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_4_ib-0', 'conv2d_2_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_8_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_5_ib-2', 'lambda_28_ib-0', 'gumbel_softmax_1_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_4_ib-1', 'batch_normalization_11_ib-0', 'activation_1_ib-3', 'b
    nodes_in_decreasing_depth = [<keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6ec6d520>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6c4499d0>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6eb7be20>, '...<67 more>']

  File ../../../usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py line 1407 function build_map : build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
                       tensor = <tf.Tensor 'lambda_28/add_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
               finished_nodes = {<keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6ebb1820>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d667f5820>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d666a4040>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6ebdb850>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d66770850>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6c48b0a0>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6c44d0a0>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d66a298b0>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d669af8e0>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d66870100>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6c486910>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d669af910>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d668d0940>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d666cc940>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d66a39160>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6698f160>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d668d0970>
            nodes_in_progress = {<keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d66595a30>}
                        layer = None
                   node_index = None
                 tensor_index = None
                         node = <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d66595a30>
                     node_key = 'lambda_28_ib-0'
                            i = 0
                            x = <tf.Tensor 'add_9:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
                layer_indices = {<keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f0d666a4c10>: 0, <keras.layers.core.Lambda object at 0x7f0d666a1190>: 1, <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f0d6ec65670>: 2, <keras.layers.core.Reshape object at 0x7f0d6ec65970>: 3, <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2DTranspose object at 0x7f0d6ec65700>: 4, <keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x7f0d6ec65d00>: 5, <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f0d6ec657c0>: 6, <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2DTranspose object at 0x7f0d6ec65610>: 7, <keras.layers.core.Reshape object at 0x7f0d6ec655e0>: 8, <keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x7f0d6ec65340>: 9, <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f0d6ec65310>: 10, <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f0d6ec651f0>: 11, <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f0d6c43ed90>: 12, <latplan.util.layers.BinaryConcrete object at 0x7f0d669193a0>: 13, <keras.layers.merge.Add object at 0x7f0d66a29040>: 14, <k
                network_nodes = {'conv2d_transpose_1_ib-2', 'conv2d_2_ib-1', 'dmerge_5_ib-0', 'conv2d_transpose_2_ib-3', 'conv2d_transpose_2_ib-2', 'reshape_4_ib-2', 'batch_normalization_10_ib-0', 'dense_8_ib-0', 'conv2d_1_ib-1', 'dropout_5_ib-3', 'dense_5_ib-1', 'lambda_14_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_7_ib-3', 'reshape_4_ib-3', 'binary_concrete_2_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_3_ib-1', 'reshape_3_ib-1', 'dense_5_ib-0', 'dropout_4_ib-2', 'activation_1_ib-2', 'batch_normalization_1_ib-0', 'lambda_18_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_7_ib-2', 'batch_normalization_6_ib-2', 'my_flatten_2_ib-0', 'binary_concrete_1_ib-0', 'dropout_3_ib-1', 'my_flatten_1_ib-0', 'gaussian_noise_1_ib-1', 'lambda_19_ib-0', 'dropout_5_ib-2', 'reshape_5_ib-3', 'dense_6_ib-3', 'reshape_3_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_4_ib-0', 'conv2d_2_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_8_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_5_ib-2', 'lambda_28_ib-0', 'gumbel_softmax_1_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_4_ib-1', 'batch_normalization_11_ib-0', 'activation_1_ib-3', 'b
    nodes_in_decreasing_depth = [<keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6ec6d520>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6c4499d0>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6eb7be20>, '...<67 more>']

  File ../../../usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py line 1380 function build_map : node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
                       tensor = <tf.Tensor 'add_9:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
               finished_nodes = {<keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6ebb1820>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d667f5820>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d666a4040>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6ebdb850>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d66770850>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6c48b0a0>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6c44d0a0>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d66a298b0>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d669af8e0>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d66870100>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6c486910>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d669af910>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d668d0940>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d666cc940>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d66a39160>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6698f160>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d668d0970>
            nodes_in_progress = {<keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d66595a30>}
                        layer = None
                   node_index = None
                 tensor_index = None
                layer_indices = {<keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x7f0d666a4c10>: 0, <keras.layers.core.Lambda object at 0x7f0d666a1190>: 1, <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f0d6ec65670>: 2, <keras.layers.core.Reshape object at 0x7f0d6ec65970>: 3, <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2DTranspose object at 0x7f0d6ec65700>: 4, <keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x7f0d6ec65d00>: 5, <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f0d6ec657c0>: 6, <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2DTranspose object at 0x7f0d6ec65610>: 7, <keras.layers.core.Reshape object at 0x7f0d6ec655e0>: 8, <keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x7f0d6ec65340>: 9, <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f0d6ec65310>: 10, <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f0d6ec651f0>: 11, <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f0d6c43ed90>: 12, <latplan.util.layers.BinaryConcrete object at 0x7f0d669193a0>: 13, <keras.layers.merge.Add object at 0x7f0d66a29040>: 14, <k
                network_nodes = {'conv2d_transpose_1_ib-2', 'conv2d_2_ib-1', 'dmerge_5_ib-0', 'conv2d_transpose_2_ib-3', 'conv2d_transpose_2_ib-2', 'reshape_4_ib-2', 'batch_normalization_10_ib-0', 'dense_8_ib-0', 'conv2d_1_ib-1', 'dropout_5_ib-3', 'dense_5_ib-1', 'lambda_14_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_7_ib-3', 'reshape_4_ib-3', 'binary_concrete_2_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_3_ib-1', 'reshape_3_ib-1', 'dense_5_ib-0', 'dropout_4_ib-2', 'activation_1_ib-2', 'batch_normalization_1_ib-0', 'lambda_18_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_7_ib-2', 'batch_normalization_6_ib-2', 'my_flatten_2_ib-0', 'binary_concrete_1_ib-0', 'dropout_3_ib-1', 'my_flatten_1_ib-0', 'gaussian_noise_1_ib-1', 'lambda_19_ib-0', 'dropout_5_ib-2', 'reshape_5_ib-3', 'dense_6_ib-3', 'reshape_3_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_4_ib-0', 'conv2d_2_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_8_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_5_ib-2', 'lambda_28_ib-0', 'gumbel_softmax_1_ib-0', 'batch_normalization_4_ib-1', 'batch_normalization_11_ib-0', 'activation_1_ib-3', 'b
    nodes_in_decreasing_depth = [<keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6ec6d520>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6c4499d0>, <keras.engine.base_layer.Node object at 0x7f0d6eb7be20>, '...<67 more>']


AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

Yet, I have used a Lambda layer to avoid this error (as advised in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/424432/no-attribute-inbound-nodes-error-even-when-using-lambda-layer-in-keras))

Any idea ?

Thanks!

**p.s:** ama3_forward_* are tensors (e.g. Tensor("add_9:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32))

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: it was in an attached file, I just put it here